# Ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `messages' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Since google did not help me in my quest to figure this out, I figured I would share it for anyone else that runs into this problem:

When attempting to save a model, I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `messages' for []:Array
0: /.../active_record/autosave_association.rb:491:in `_ensure_no_duplicate_errors'
1: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
2: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:246:in `block in halting'
3: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
4: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
5: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
6: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
7: /.../active_support/callbacks.rb:825:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
8: /.../active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:110:in `run_validations!'
9: /.../active_model/validations.rb:335:in `valid?'
```

Example model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def do_stuff
    @errors = []
    @errors << 'Bad stuff' if self.bar > 4
    @errors
  end

end
```

Example code:

```
foo = Foo.first
foo.do_stuff
foo.save # or foo.valid?, etc.
```

Answer (score 6):

**The Cause**

The cause of this error message is that the `Foo` class creates an instance level `@errors` variable.

ActiveRecord keeps track of database errors in a model's `errors` variable. When you try to validate a model, it checks for error messages in this variable.

**The Solution**

Change `@errors` to a different name (e.g. `@foo_errors`).